# How to access "main" querystring from ActionMethod called from Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jquery, partial-views

In an MVC project, I have a partial

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial");
```

which calls a controller method (using AJAX with jQuery) via URL

```
'/Home/MyActionMethod?type=myType&sort=az&page=1'
```

The Home controller contains MyActionMethod, which returns a PartialViewResult.
MyActionMethod has parameters matching those in the URL, which are mapped as per usual.

My question is how to access the top level querystring from MyActionMethod, because I want to include extra values in there? By top level I mean the one seen in the browser, as opposed to the one sent to MyActionMethod from _MyPartial

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include them as query string parameters when performing your AJAX call. So when building the link on the server, read the query string parameters and append them to those that you have already.